# policy numbers formats sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to achieve the following, anyone please help.

```
[Policy Number]  format
123456789        AAAAAAAAA
123456           AAAAAA
12345678         AAAAAAAA
12               AA
1234             AAAA
12345678         AAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 5):

One option uses `REPLICATE`:

```
SELECT
    [Policy Number],
    REPLICATE('A', LEN([Policy Number])) AS format
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

This option would only work if you are using SQL Server 2008 or later.  Note that I assume the policy number is text.  If it's actually numeric, then you would first have to convert it to text, e.g. `CONVERT(varchar(10), [Policy Number])`.

Comment: Microsoft has a very unhelpful habit of editing their documentation to show the currently kind-of-supported version of the product as the earliest possible version for a feature. In fact `replicate` existed at least back in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @GSerg Didn't know.  But doesn't surprise me at all.